# xCode command line tools installed, but not visible

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, automation, appium

I'd like to run appium to do automated tests of my app. For that I need to run some commands using command line tools. It's my first time trying to do that.

If I go to `preferences > downloads > "command line tools"` show up as "installed"

But where do I open it? I checked `XCode > Open Developer Tool` - it's not there. A hint or a link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a graphical program; its run from the *command line*. Typically, they are installed in `/usr/bin`.

For information on how to install it, try here on **[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools).**

To get the various list of tools that are installed, see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344107/xcode-4-3-command-line-tools).**